# How to retrieve a mp4 file into KdenLive for Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, video, mp4, kdenlive

I've installed Kedenlive on Ubuntu 18.04. And I have also downloaded an mp4 video from AndroidAir; the video was originally recorded on my phone (Huawei Mate 10 Pro). When I tried to retrieve the mp4 video into Kdenlive, the software didn't recognize the video file. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Have you installed necessary codecs by running command `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras` ???

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was able to install it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Install the necessary codecs using command:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: I get this error: E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras